# failed to synchronize cache for repo AppStream

Tags: linux, compilation, yum, centos8

My centos machine has no connection to internet. I need to install make utility to compile some modules from source code. I am getting this error while i run yum install make. Even if i run yum module list , it gives me same error. need help at earliest.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons for this issue. The most common ones are:

- Incorrect date and time settings
- Old dnf cache available or expired
- CentOS baseURL

**How to fix Incorrect date and time settings:**

The timedatectl command is a new utility tool in CentOS 7/8. It is a replacement for old traditional date command used in sysvinit daemon-based Linux distributions.

Find the current date and time of your system. Make sure it is correct with the proper time zone.

```
[root@centos ~]# timedatectl
[root@centos ~]# timedatectl set-timezone "America/Chicago"
[root@centos ~]# date
```

**How to clear Old/expired dnf cache:**

```
[root@centos ~]# dnf clean all
[root@centos ~]# rm -rf /var/cache/dnf
```

https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#clean-command-label

**How to change CentOS baseURL from mirror.centos.org to vault.centos.org:**

/etc/yum.repos.d/

CentOS Linux 8 had reached the End Of Life (EOL) on December 31st, 2021. It means that CentOS 8 will no longer receive development resources from the official CentOS project. After Dec 31st, 2021, if you need to update your CentOS, you need to change the mirrors to **vault.centos.org** where they will be archived permanently. Alternatively, you may want to upgrade to CentOS Stream or migrate from CentOS to Rocky Linux.  Or AlmaLinux, which I'd recommend.

https://mirrors.almalinux.org/isos.html

Answer (score 0):

It needs to contact the internet to be able to access the Centos Software Repository so that it can download `make`. If you are still seeing this when you machine has internet then it may be the same as  this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61522502/288022