# Install Python 3 on Centos 8 returns "Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'BaseOS'"

Tags: python, linux, centos

I am using CentOS 8. I'm trying to install Python 3. Command: `sudo dnf install python3`. Error:

> Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'BaseOS'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Centos did something funny with the value of `$releasever` in that they were using the full version `8.0.1905` instead of just `8`. When the new version `8.1.1911` was released they archived the old version. If you do in install of old media or use an old vagrant box this may cause the following issue:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo dnf upgrade
CentOS-8.0 - AppStream                                                                                                                                                                                        1.6 kB/s |  38  B     00:00    
CentOS-8.0 - Base                                                                                                                                                                                             748  B/s |  38  B     00:00    
CentOS-8.0 - Extras                                                                                                                                                                                           126  B/s |  38  B     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8.0 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                       53 kB/s |  63 kB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8.0 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                               80 kB/s |  63 kB     00:00    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'AppStream', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'BaseOS', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'extras', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'epel-modular', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'epel', ignoring this repo.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

The fix for this is to specify the Centos version on the `dnf` command line using the `--releasever` option like this:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo dnf upgrade --releasever=8
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                                                                          164 kB/s | 7.0 MB     00:43    
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                                                                                                               313 kB/s | 2.2 MB     00:07    
CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                                                                                                                                             5.1 kB/s | 5.5 kB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                         63 kB/s | 116 kB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                5.9 MB/s | 6.5 MB     00:01    
Dependencies resolved.
```

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the baseurl from mirror.centos.org to vault.centos.org in the appropriate repo file here:

/etc/yum.repos.d/

Comment: In my CentOS-Base.repo file, the "baseurl=" is listed below  "mirrorlist=" and is commented out,. What should I do?

Comment: If I recall, I was using Alma Linux when I posted this, which is the new academic replacement for CentOS due to the recent 'end of life' of CentOS.  So Alma Linux probably uses the mirrors and repositories that CentOS used.  If I can find my notes or remember when I wake up tomorrow, I'll post another comment.  If believe the yum command is affected and errors out if incorrect.  I can't remember if there is a step after doing what I did here and re-running the yum command.  It might involve something with dnf.

Comment: If you want, post a question of your own and send a comment here with the new question and I'll dig into it tomorrow to help you.